# JavaAutomatic type promotion

Tags: java

When I write `short a = 2 * 3;` then I don't encounter any issue but when I write

```
short a = 2;
a = a * 3;
```

then it shows typecasting error.

I don't understand this behavior, I know whenever we are performing any expression then all the operands are converted into int, so according to this logic I should also get error for the former one.

Please can this logic be explained?

Comment: Presumably because the first one can be evaluated at compile-time, and it obviously fits into a short.

Comment: @khelwood there are no `short` compile time constants

Comment: @Eugene It sounds like you think you're disagreeing with me, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not, I *thought* you are implying that it's a `short` compile time constant, which you are not after reading your comment again. my bad!

Comment: @Max,So If the operation is precomputed then it would mean that operation's result is type independent and if the result is compatible with variable's type then it would get stored there without any issue.
But for long var=1000*60*60*24*365 , only 32bit result is stored in the variable even when result is 36bit long and there should not be any issue storing it in long. The desired result can only be achieved when we define it like long var=1000*60*60*24*365l. So why this happens?

Comment: @Eugene same query for you too

Comment: why do we have to forcefully typecast it in this case even when result is compatible with the destination?

Comment: @SiddharthaChoudhury  you do understand that `1000*60*60*24*365` is actually an `int`, right? it gets trunked to an `int` that is that fits into a `long`. otherwise you are very unclear here... care to explain even more?

Comment: See you have said that 
short a=2*3 is equivalent to short a = (short) 2*3
which means result is automatically typecasted to its destination
So according to that logic
1)long var=1000*60*60*24*365 is equivalent to 2)long var=(long) 1000*60*60*24*365
But result of 1) is different that 2)
So is it like the operation's result is first fit into int and then it is type casted according to its destination like
short a= (short) ( (int) 2*3) or long var = (long) ((int) 1000*60*60*24*365) ?

Comment: @SiddharthaChoudhury *which means result is automatically typecasted to its destination* this is a conclusion *you* made. I said its *like* this so that you could understand a bit ore, but it is not like that in reality.  Every operation on numbers unless specified with `l/L` for example are automatically converted to `int`. But in the case of `short a = 2 * 3` the compiler does see that a `2 * 3` can be a short (it fits). Probably the better explanation would be that `short s = 6S` if such a thing exited, `S` meaning short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone will sure cite the `JLS` here, but in plain english:

```
short a = 2 * 3;
```

compiler "will see" that `2 * 3` is actually immediately `6` (which is an `int` and fits into that `short`). It's like doing:

```
short a = (short) 2 * 3;
```

The other case:

```
a = a * 3;
```

*You* can tell that that is `6` also - compiler can't. It sees `a * 3` as an `int` that it has no idea if it will fit into `a`, so it issues an error.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `a * 3` is an `int` because `3` is considered such by the compiler.

You need to perform a type cast like this: `short a=2;a=(short) (a*3);`

The reason is that the compiler is able to deduce at compile-time, that the result of `2*3` fits in a `short` (and actually performs the calculation). `a*3` on the other hand is performed at runtime, and the result of this runtime calculation is an `int`.

You can verify this if you compile this class with javac:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short a=2;
        a = (short) (a*3);
   }
}
```

And then decompile the bytecode with `javap.exe -c Test.class`:

```
$ javap.exe -c Test.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: iconst_3
       4: imul
       5: i2s
       6: istore_1
       7: return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=2*3;
```

Here the compiler precomputes `2*3`, so it has a constant value `6`.

This is the exact same thing as writing `a=6;`.

```
a=2;
a=a*3;
```

Here the compiler cannot precompute the result, as `a` is a variable and can have any value. Since `a` can have any value, `a*3` could give a result too big for a `short`, hence the error.